# Cardinality of $A^B$ when $A > B \ge \aleph_0$

Tags: cardinals

For an infinite cardinal *A*, then

1. if $B$ is finite $A^B = A$
2. If $B$ is infinite and $B \ge A$ then $A^B \ge A^A \ge 2^A > A$
3. What if $B$ is infinite, but $B < A$, i.e. $A > B \ge \aleph_0$. Is there a relationship between $A^B$ and $A$ in this case ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can't quite always say. The continuum hypothesis is equivalent to $\aleph_1^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_1$. But it is not provable, so this equality can hold or fail. But $\aleph_1\leq\aleph_1^{\aleph_0}$ is provable. Therefore,
$$\lnot\sf CH\iff\aleph_1<\aleph_1^{\aleph_0}.$$

So the only thing you can *really* say is that $A\leq A^B$. Nothing much more.

---

You can also find more intricate problems.

It is always true that $\kappa^{\operatorname{cf}(\kappa)}>\kappa$. So for example, we know that $\aleph_\omega^{\aleph_0}>\aleph_\omega$. But by how much? Is it $\aleph_{\omega+1}$? Is it $\aleph_{\omega+2}$? Is it $2^{\aleph_\omega}$? We can't say, even if we assume that $2^{\aleph_n}<\aleph_\omega$ for all $n<\omega$.

Even worse, what about $\aleph_{\omega_1}^{\aleph_0}$? As far as provability goes, it has no obligation being larger, but it can and it can stay the same (not simultaneously, of course).

But look at $\beth_{\omega_1}$. We can prove that $\beth_{\omega_1}^{\aleph_0}=\beth_{\omega_1}$. So you can't prove exponentiation always grows, and you can prove that it *can* grow in the case of singular cardinals.

Comment: Thanks. If one accepts the continuum hypothesis, is there then a relationship that either $A^B = A$ or $A^B > A$ ?

Comment: Well, then you can violate this bond of trust between cardinals on higher levels. Generally you need to assume something like $\sf GCH$ or a specific failure thereof in order to conclude anything particular on cardinals.

Comment: OK: as I understand GHC the infinite cardinals are defined by a complete countably infinite list $\aleph_0, \aleph_1, ......$ where $\aleph_{n+1} = 2^{\aleph_n}$. So if one accepts GCH is there a definite relationship of equality or inferiority between $\aleph_n^{\aleph_m}$ and $\aleph_n$ when $m < n$ ?

Comment: Under $\sf GCH$ we can prove the following: $$\kappa^\lambda=\begin{cases}\kappa+ & \lambda<\operatorname{cf}(\kappa)\\\lambda^+ &\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$ And for any ordinal, $\aleph_{\alpha+1}$ is always regular, namely $\operatorname{cf}(\aleph_{\alpha+1})=\aleph_{\alpha+1}$. So in the case of $m,n<\omega$ it immediately implies that $\aleph_n^{\aleph_m}=\aleph_n$ if and only if $m<n$.

Comment: Thanks again: if I understand correctly then if GCH is accepted it follows that if $A > B \ge \aleph_0$ then $A^B = A$ ?

Comment: No. You can always prove that $\kappa^{\operatorname{cf}(\kappa)}>\kappa$. So you can always prove that $\aleph_\omega^{\aleph_0}>\aleph_\omega$.